Advertising Test Beginning Nov 13 2024
We’ve been exploring the concept of using open auction to manage advertising on some Stack Exchange sites. Under this model, advertisers (who have been organized into categories based on their products) “bid” for an advertising spot. There is a floor price - a minimum price for the spot, and all bids must exceed that floor price.  This community will be testing the open auction experiment, beginning on November 13, 2024.  For more information or to provide feedback on the experiment, please refer to the post on Meta Stack Exchange.

Historically, Stack Exchange was quite tolerant of users who were uninterested in the advertising experience. The attitude was generally that if someone doesn't want to see an advertisement, then Stack Exchange doesn't want to bother to show it to them. I vaguely remember that this included an option for users above some reputation limit to reduce their exposure to advertisements altogether. It certainly included a commitment not to do battle with the various adblocking software.
Is the company's plan to continue to have this respect for the user experience?

yes.  In fact, we enabled the reduced ads privilege on all the impacted sites prior to this announcement.

And yet I am seeing ads when I did not before. I would appreciate not having to see them.

@mmesser314 Please post a new Meta question describing what you're seeing.

Rob requested I describe what ads I am seeing. The easiest way is a screenshot. I see ads like this intermittently. Before the test started, I did not see ads.

